# problemas con condicional if con string en android java

Tags: java, android, eclipse, condiciones

cuando intento utilizar equals  no me aparece nada cuando pongo la palabra, este es el codigo(son pruevas),tambien intente solo ponerle comillas a lo que esta entre parentecis de los "equals".

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
     public String  Hola,Que ;
    public TextView resultado,resultado2,resultado3;
       public EditText A;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        A=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        resultado = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView5);
        resultado2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView6);
        resultado3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView7);
            }

         public void Calcular(View view){

            if(A.equals(Hola)){
           resultado.setText("adios");
           resultado2.setText(" :c");
           resultado3.setText("sep");
               }

             if(A.equals(Que)){ 
             resultado.setText("tal");
             resultado2.setText("--");
             resultado3.setText("--");
           }
           }
```

Comment: Bienvenido Luis, por lo que se ve solo has hecho la declaración a las variables Hola y Que, pero no veo donde hayas hecho la asignación de alguna cadena a esas variables, y sin saber cual es su contenido lo evalúas dentro de un if. Asignale valores a esas dos variables para solucionar ese problema.

Answer (score 0):

En realidad la situacion aqui es: como obtener el texto de un EditText.

```
  A=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
```

En esa linea lo que estas haciendo es asignandole a tu variable A el objeto EditText  editText1, allí no estas obteniendo el texto.

Para hacer la comparacion del texto que esta en en el Editext A:

```
if(A.getText().toString().trim().equals("hola")){
    //con .getText() obtienes lo que esta en EditText
    // con .toString()  lo conviertes s texto
    // con .trim() quitas los espacions en blanco al inicio y al final del la palabra

}
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias igmer